# Editor Template Not working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying out the Editor Template in MVC 3

My model class is

```
public class BookViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

I have create a partial view for Editor template and put that in a EditorTemplates folder with name **Text.cshtml**. following is the partial view

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<string>
<p> Write the name of author</p> @Html.TextBox(Model)
```

and I used @Html.EditorFor in the view page

```
<p> Name : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p>

<p> Author</p> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
```

But when I run the program what I see is only an empty TextBox. I should see a TextBox filled with Author Name right?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor template should be:

```
@model String
<p> Write the name of author</p> @Html.TextBox("name of the textbox", Model)
```

The first parameter of the @Html.TextBox() helper can be an empty string as well, but its not recommended

Comment: see my updated answer, i forgot to add the name parameter in the @Html.TextBox("NameOfTextBox", Model)

Comment: you are correct. The problem was, I had not put the correct parameters in @Html.TextBox().. damn I missed it